# InvalidArgumentError while training long short term memory network with Python/Keras (Audio classification)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to Keras and I am trying to build a recurrent neural network to classify Audio files.

During the training, I am receiving an `InvalidArgumentError: indices[28,0] = -711 is not in [0, 20000)`.

I have found various topics talking about this error but, to be honest, I did not understand what I have to change in the parameters I am passing to the network in order to help it managing the negative values I have in the training array.

Below the code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional

max_features = 20000
maxlen = 40
batch_size = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=4,
          validation_data=[X_test, y_test])
```

Error below:

```
Train...
Train on 964 samples, validate on 476 samples
Epoch 1/4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3452d23cb8b5> in <module>()
     12           batch_size=batch_size,
     13           epochs=4,
---> 14           validation_data=[X_test, y_test])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1037                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1038                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1039                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1040 
   1041     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    197                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    198 
--> 199                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    200                 outs = to_list(outs)
    201                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: indices[28,0] = -711 is not in [0, 20000)
     [[{{node embedding_3/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_1/Adam/Assign_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_3/embeddings/read, embedding_3/Cast, training_1/Adam/gradients/embedding_3/embedding_lookup_grad/concat/axis)]]
```

**EDIT1**: X_train is the float32 array below

```
array([[-5.79938449e+02,  6.63875936e+01, -6.75054944e+00, ...,
        -2.89458464e+00, -2.30009868e+00, -2.34216322e+00],
       [-3.38924973e+02,  1.60668197e+01, -5.39871140e+01, ...,
         1.27180395e+00,  4.28090614e+00,  2.01538667e+00],
       [-5.53199739e+02,  3.45314936e+01, -1.68711443e+01, ...,
        -9.47345310e-02, -1.04780706e-02,  1.69060756e-01],
       ...,
       [-5.91902354e+02,  6.14329122e+01,  1.43761675e+00, ...,
        -4.38644438e+00, -3.67977820e+00, -1.89899207e+00],
       [-7.04889969e+02,  6.24931510e+01,  1.90338300e+01, ...,
        -1.47540089e+00, -1.75498741e+00, -4.55713837e-01],
       [-8.24296641e+02,  7.43124586e+01,  1.43319513e+01, ...,
        -7.60749297e-01, -1.05324700e+00, -8.54044186e-01]])
```

Comment: What is stored in `X_train`? Are you sure about using an Embedding layer for this task, i.e. classification of audio files?

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I have added the structure of the array at the end of the question. Not sure about the Embedding layer, I am just testing!

Comment: Remove the embedding layer. Embedding layer is just a (trainable) look-up table which is mostly used in NLP tasks. And it takes integers as input. It does not make sense to use it here with the audio files as input.